# 3D Earth globe on google maps API JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

*Short question:*

Is there a way to represent the 3D earth globe with google maps web API?

---

On [google maps](https://www.google.fr/maps/@18.4980181,7.5767451,3z), we can now visualize the earth as a globe in 3D.

Here is an example:

[image: consult https://www.google.fr/maps/@18.4980181,7.5767451,3z]

---

I am developing an HTML project with google maps API and I would like to use this earth representation on my website.

However, I do not find any topic about this subject.

Is there a way to represent the 3D earth globe with google maps API as on the [google maps web site](https://www.google.fr/maps/@18.4980181,7.5767451,3z)3D?

---

Here is an example of my map (it is of course an extract of my code to clarify the question):

```js
var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Here is a picture of my map on my website:

[image]

This map only represents the earth as a planisphere. How may I have the same result as on the google maps web site?

---

**Notice**:
I found this [post](https://mobile.twitter.com/googlemaps/status/1025130620471656449) in twitter witch introduces the feature on the google maps web site.

Comment: You may try [CesiumJs](https://cesiumjs.org/)

Comment: Well, I have already tried it but it does not fit with my web app @JônatasCastro .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe this feature is not available in the API yet.

I can see a feature request in Google issue tracker that looks like your question:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111576221

I would suggest staring the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications. Hopefully one day Google will implement this feature in the API.